# How to set execution of operation on table on specific day in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to do some operation on table, i.e. update on specific day of week, i.e. every Monday using only stored procedure - no triggers.

I.E. I have in the stored procedure:

```
update table_1 
set col1 = val1
where conditions;
```

I want to make working this every week on specific day.

I will be glad for any idea.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using the Oracle job scheduler.  You can set the job up to run whenever you want. You can read more about the job scheduler [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72262), and I've included an example below.

```
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name           =>  'YOUR_JOB_NAME',
      job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      job_action         =>  'SOME_SCHEMA.SOME_PROC',
      start_date         =>  to_date('20180313-23:30','YYYYMMDD-HH24:MI') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern',
      repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1', /* every day */
      auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
      comments           =>  'Job to do something useful',
      enabled            =>  true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree that would be good solution of this problem, but I have to do without scheduler.

Comment: @Ron - "I want to make working this every week on specific day" - To meet that requirement, you'll need a job scheduler of some sort, even if it's not the Oracle one.

Comment: I believe, I will find solution. But - one more time - I agree, that using job here is the best thing.

Comment: Why do you "have to do without schedule"?  Like @dcp, if you want something to happen at a specific time, then -- BY DEFINITION - you have to use a scheduler of _some_ sort.  Either oracle's, the OS's, or some third-party.

Comment: @EdStevens formal recommendation for this task. Not my idea.

Comment: "formal recommendation for this task. Not my idea".  Well, to do what you say, a scheduler, _some_ scheduler, is an absolute requirement.  I'd be pushing back and asking some questions.  As it stands, your 'requirement/recommendation' is like being required to drive a gasoline-powered automobile without the use of gasoline.

Comment: You have two options: 1) ask an employee to type "execute myprocedure" every Monday  or 2) let a computer do that for you. The software that does that is commonly called scheduler.

Comment: @EdStevens Very good comparison, I like it :D But it i real situation, so I don't :/

Comment: @wolφi I know. I told it today, but the answer was "try do this in this procedure, without using jobs".

Comment: So did you _ask_ them _why_ they don't want you to use jobs? Is their objection specifically to using Oracle's scheduler?  Or do they think that there is some magic method to  have something occur at a certain time without some means of "scheduling" it? If the latter, then there request is impossible to fullfill. Period. Full stop.  Unless, of course, they are willing to commit someone to sit at their keyboard at the not-scheduled time and submit it manually.

Comment: On some large sites there is a policy that scheduling should be managed by the scheduling team and the tools supplied by them, such as AutoSys or Control M. If so, fair enough, but please tag the toolset available to you for this task.

Comment: I suppose you could have it try once every 24 hours using `dbms_lock.sleep`, and add `where to_char(sysdate,'Dy','nls_language=English') = 'Mon'` to the WHERE clause (or maybe a separate test in the procedure would be better). Then maybe once it has run successfully it could sleep for a week. You'd just start the procedure and it would run until you stopped it.

Comment: Actually @EdStevens "someone to sit at their keyboard ... and submit it manually" would be - ugh a "job scheduler". And there is still the possibility the the scheduler is "down".

Comment: @Belayer - hence my sarcastic "not-scheduled time".  :-)

Comment: @William Robertson - But then if the Oracle instance was taken down, the proc would stop and it wouldn't restart automatically when the instance was restarted.

Comment: @dcp good point. I remember one site that had a PC with an [autoexec.bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOEXEC.BAT) that called SQL\*Plus and started the backup, and the PC was on a timer plug that switched it on every night. Perhaps the OP could do something similar.

Comment: Thank you all. @EdStevens they are using jobs, but not in this task. Weird, I know.

Comment: Well, the question as to the nature and reasoning for their objection still stands ....